# Prepend/Append an Image only in active class by Click Function

Tags: jquery

I know its something that you don't meet very often..but I'll try describe it.

I have a list of links. I also have a script that makes the link that has been clicked active by adding a class to it. Every time a link clicked, we have a different active link.

Problem is that every time this happens, I want an image prepend to this ACTIVE link.
I manage to add this image but unfortunately script add this image EVERY TIME that clicked on link and not only for the active link. I want this image to be prepend ONLY for active class link.

My script is:

```
$(function(){
    var sidebar = $('#sidebar');
    sidebar.delegate('a.inactive','click',function(){
        sidebar.find('.active').toggleClass('active inactive');
        $(this).toggleClass('active inactive');
        $(this).prepend('<img class="gallery-selected-bg" src="http://www.saugeentimes.com/496%20Liz/girls%20soccer%20aug%204,%202010/soccer-ball-small.jpg">');
    });
});
```

Sorry if I did not describe it well, you can see my code please... If I could tell it simpler this I want is only one ball for only the active link that may be changes by click.

**http://jsfiddle.net/dstpt/390/**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your code and cleaned it up abit...

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dstpt/395/

Basically I'm using CSS :before to show your image.

HTML (simplified your version to only need the active class)

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="1" class="active">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="2">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="3">3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS (simplified it as well)

```
$(function(){
    var sidebar = $('#sidebar');
    sidebar.delegate('a','click',function(){
        sidebar.find('a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

CSS

```
a {
    border:0;
    background:0;
    font-size:30px;
    color:navy;
}

a.active {
    background-color:#ccd9ff;
    border-radius:15px 15px;
    font-size:30px;
    color:Red;
}

a.active:before {
    content: url('http://www.saugeentimes.com/496%20Liz/girls%20soccer%20aug%204,%202010/soccer-ball-small.jpg');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a fine solution! The reason i use prepend img is because i want an position:absolute image on a position:relative image for having an image (overlay) on top of another image. But i suppose thats works fine with your way too.

Comment: Yep, I prefer to use CSS as opposed to javascript as much as I can (less code, and usually better performance) and if you can accept not caring about IE7 or even IE8 viewers, go full on CSS3!

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
$("img.gallery-selected-bg").remove();
```

after **line 11** of your script.

It will remove all the previously added images.

## Here is your updated [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n1k1ch/dstpt/391/)

Comment: Well, i must think more simply immediately.. Thank you!

Comment: Whilst this works, you should accept @Populus answer. He did more for you :)

Answer (score 0):

i fixed you fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dstpt/392/

you need to remove the image from the `li` . before attaching it to the selected

```
$('li .gallery-selected-bg').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know your question didn't have a CSS tag, but another possible solution to your problem is to add the image with a `.active:before` css entry. The benefit of this being that your current JS will work just fine.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/dstpt/394/)**

CSS:

```
.active:before {
  content:"";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  background: url('http://www.saugeentimes.com/496%20Liz/girls%20soccer%20aug%204,%202010/soccer-ball-small.jpg') no-repeat;
}
```