# Images change on click and revert back

Tags: jquery, css

I've got a list of 3 images.

I want each of them to change to a different image when clicked and revert back when another is clicked.

[image: purple image indicates active, green inactive]

I know there has to be a simple solution but I'm stuck.

Hopefully that's clear, if not I can clarify more.

This is the closest solution to what I'm looking for that I could find (kinda)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21491487

Comment: Could you please show us your code that you have tried within the question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How are you showing these images? Are you doing it with an html `img` tag or via css `background-image`

Comment: @ROOH you can use jsFiddle to show the existing code: https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/fnbsod7z/5/), what i did:

1. Adding a class name `.clickable` to these image to pick them easily.
2. Store each click image in a custom `data-clicked` in order to retrieve it and make use of it replacing the original `src` image when it get clicked
3. Also we add another *empty* custom `data-normal` which we write in the value of the `src` value into it to preserve the original `src` value so we make use of it to put the original value back to each image `src` as we click image and use this value to reset all images clicked value
4. Then activate the `img` that was clicked only by writing the value of the `data-clicked` to this image `src`.

```js
$('.clickable').each(function(){
    // initially, set each image data-normal value to that image src
    var eachSRC = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).attr('data-normal', eachSRC);
});
$('.clickable').on('click', function(){
    $('.clickable').each(function(){
        // store each image's data-normal value in a variable and set each image src to this value
        var origSRC = $(this).attr('data-normal');
        $(this).attr('src', origSRC);
    });
    // replace the src of the image was clicked with the data-click value
    var hoverSRC = $(this).attr('data-clicked');
 $(this).attr('src',hoverSRC);
});
```

```css
.clickable{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="clickable" src="//placehold.it/150x150?text=image1" data-normal="" data-clicked="//placehold.it/150x150/008800/ffffff/?text=image1">
<img class="clickable" src="//placehold.it/150x150?text=image2" data-normal="" data-clicked="//placehold.it/150x150/008800/ffffff/?text=image2">
<img class="clickable" src="//placehold.it/150x150?text=image3" data-normal="" data-clicked="//placehold.it/150x150/008800/ffffff/?text=image3" >
```

** *Please note that next time you post a question make sure you provide code snippets within it so that others can understand your problem more and can easier modify it to give you a better answer, here in StackOverflow we appreciate well asked and formatted questions*